# Reddit POST Request - Error 403 (php/curl)

Tags: php, curl, reddit

I'm trying to connect with the Reddit API and programatically submit posts. I have managed to return an access token but I get 403 error when trying to do the actual submission. Any advice?

Get Access Token: (works, returns token)

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'CLIENTID:CLIENTSECRET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$token = json_decode($return, true);
```

Submit Link: (error 403)

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/submit?kind=link&sr=news&title=TITLE&r=news&url='.urlencode('http://example.com'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'CLIENTID:CLIENTSECRET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: bearer ".$token['access_token']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($return, true);
```

Comment: **TL/DR** Reddit is telling you that you don't have permission to do the action you are trying to do - "_A 403 error response indicates that the client's request is formed correctly, but the REST API refuses to honor it i.e. the user does not have the necessary permissions for the resource. A 403 response is not a case of insufficient client credentials; that would be 401 (“Unauthorized”)._"

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you for your response. I'm still not sure where to go from here, there's surprising few code examples online and I've followed Reddit API documentation to the best of my abilities. I've managed to get APIs from Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest working, but Reddit is proving a challenge.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the documentation to see what you are doing is correct, but I'm assuming it is considering the error you are getting. Perhaps where you are trying to post to has permissions not allowing you to do it? If you are supposed to be able to submit to this specific endpoint, and it's not letting you, the issue is likely on Reddits end (not yours). You may be able to post a thread somewhere _on reddit_ for more localized support for the issue you are getting.

Comment: Ah right, I shall do that :) thank you for confirming, I wasn't sure whether or not I was doing something wrong with the request.

Comment: Well, I can't tell _for sure_ that the issue isn't on your end, but the error you are getting would suggest that.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: I got it working with help from the guys over at /r/redditdev - turns out I needed to use different endpoints as I wasn't using a wrapper. I wouldn't have been able to do it otherwise as there appears to be no public documentation on this so thank you for your suggestion to go to Reddit for help, it paid off :)

Comment: @user11588722 do you have the updated endpoint you could share please :-)