# reddit api 403 forbidden

Tags: php, reddit

I have the following code;

It all works and I am able to obtain an access token but I get a `403 Forbidden Error` when trying to use the submit endpoint. I saw a previous post that uses identical code pretty much, that mentioned that the endpoint is incorrect, [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295701/reddit-post-request-error-403-php-curl).

I can't seem to find the updated endpoint; Is anyone familiar with the reddit api and would be able to help find the problem here. Thanks :-)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$clientID = '****'; // app client id
$clientSecret = '****'; // app secret 
$redditUsername = '****'; // reddit username 
$redditPassword = '****'; // reddit password

// Post to subreddit info

$title = '****';
$r = '****';
$kind = '****';
$url = 'http://example.com';

$ch = curl_init('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&username=' . $redditUsername . '&password=' . $redditPassword . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '' . $clientID . ':' . $clientSecret . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$token = json_decode($return, true);

print_r($token);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/submit?kind=link&sr=' . $r . '&title=' . $title . '&r=' . $r . '&url='.urlencode($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '' . $clientID . ':' . $clientSecret . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: bearer " . $token['access_token'] . ""));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($return, true);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: According to the official documentation, there's an endpoint that doesn't include the version at [`/api/submit`](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_submit). Does that work?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I seem to get the same error

Comment: I also added a user agent to the request incase that was causing the problem but same issue

Comment: You are requesting a `client_credentials` grant, which doesn't have a username and password by definition. I'm guessing Reddit is just ignoring those parts of the query string. Maybe you want a [password grant](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example) instead?

Comment: It is possible there is slight issue with this line ;  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: bearer ' . $token['access_token'] . ''));`

Comment: and yes I think `client_credentials` is correct I didn't realize that I didn't need the username and password.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think you are right about the grant_type, when I change the grant_type to password I get incorrect grant type? Any ideas?

Comment: Although I work with OAuth a lot, I unfortunately don't know the specifics of Reddit's API. My recommendation (if you haven't done so already) would be to read through their [OAuth stuff](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2), as well as their [App Types](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/oauth2-app-types), and maybe just play around with their [Quick Start](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example), focusing on the CLI curl version. Once you get that working, try porting that curl to PHP's curl.